# Click event firing for all previously clicked elements

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a drag and drop email builder in JQuery and I'm facing a problem with a click event. In essence I am binding a click to any editable buttons in my template (class dynamic-button). This brings up a modal where you can change the button text and URL. Once you save from the modal (#save-button) it updates the HTML for the button within the iframe.

What's essentially happening is that the first button (assigned to var btn) will update just fine. When I however click to edit the second one, it updates the first one as well. This then continues on and on, always updating all the buttons I clicked previously.

What's strange about this also is that I have several other 'dynamic' elements such as images and paragraphs that follow the same pattern, but don't have this problem - seems to only be on these buttons.

This is my code. *emailFrame* in this is just the iframe assigned to a variable. The first few lines gets the current values and plugs them into the modal form. The click event for *#save-button* then grabs the new values from the modal and assigns them to the *btn*.

```
emailFrame.contents().find('body').on('click', '.dynamic-button', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault()

            var btn = $(this)
            var url = btn.attr('href')
            var cta = btn.text()

            $('#button-modal').addClass('active')
            $('select[name="button-cta"]').val(cta)
            $('input[name="button-url"]').val(url)

            $('body').on('click', '#save-button', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                var saveBtn = $(this)
                var newCta = $('select[name="button-cta"]').val()
                saveBtn.text('Button Saved')
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    saveBtn.text('Save Button Settings')
                }, 2000)
                btn.html(newCta)
                btn.attr('href', $('input[name="button-url"]').val())
            })
})
```

The HTML for the button is fairly straightforward, it's in tables as it's an email:

```
<td align="center" role="presentation" bgcolor="#FA9D1E" style="border:none;border-radius:3px;cursor:auto;height:32px;mso-padding-alt:0px 16px;background:#FA9D1E;padding-left:16px; padding-right:16px;" valign="middle">
   <a class="dynamic-button" href="#" style="display:inline-block;background:#FA9D1E;color:#0A0A0D;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;line-height:16px;margin:0;text-decoration:none;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0px 0px;mso-padding-alt:0px;border-radius:3px; font-weight: bold;" target="_blank">Contact us</a>
</td>
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, perhaps it's the way I'm assigning that variable. Any ideas?

Comment: It would be helpful if you used the snippet tool (`<>`) to include a working example of the problem so we can see it.

Comment: Thanks @CarstenLøvboAndersen. I unfortunately can't, this is not for a personal project and my corporate firewall is blocking me from adding a snippet. I will see if I can make another plan.

Comment: How can you firewall block you from using the Stack Overflow snippet tool? You have already completed the 2 steps thats should be required to create a snippet here. 1: Copy paste your code. 2 use Stack Overflow

Comment: The problem is because you're nesting your event handlers. Don't do that. Move the `#save-button` event handler outside the `.dynamic-button` one.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan, I don't use JQuery often and knew it was something stupid.